# How do I store Set/HashSet in Object?

Tags: java, object, set, hashset

```
 public HashSet<String> Red;
 public HashSet<String> Blue;
 public HashSet<String> Colors;

public Data(HashSet<String> red, HashSet<String> blue, HashSet<String> colors) {
  Red = red;
  Blue = blue;
  Colors = colors;
}
```

I try to store 3 Set / HashSet inside this Object. Is this way to correct way, could I acces due the object the Set/HashSet, like normal ones:

```
public Set<String> Red = new HashSet<String>();
```

Comment: It's really not clear what you're trying to do or what the code you've given *doesn't* do. Do you need to take a copy of the sets you're passed, for example, or not? What do you mean by "I must be able to copy keys of Colors to Red or Blue"? Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: You should start with the [HashSet Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html)

Comment: But must it be: public HashSet<String> Red; or public Set<String> Red; or public Set<String> Red = new HashSet<String>();. That is were I don't get it in this case.

Comment: @user1621988 you should edit your question and add relevant code there instead of in the comments

Answer (score 1):

**If you are asking how to access the `HashMap`s inside your `Data` object**

To access one of the three HashSets, you would create a new Data object and access the public field of choice after the Data object has been initialized:

```
HashSet<String> setOne = new HashSet<String>();
HashSet<String> setTwo = new HashSet<String>();
HashSet<String> setThree = new HashSet<String>();

Data d = new Data(setOne, setTwo, setThree);
d.Blue.add("this will be added to setTwo");
```

Normally however, you would want not to have public fields, but instead make them private and provide getter/setter methods, as this will provide [encapsulation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29).

**If you are asking whether you should refer to the interface or class**

First: *HashSet is a concrete class and Set is an interface.*
Also: *The reference type decides what methods you can call upon an object. (This would be the left side of the equals sign, while the right side is the dynamic type).*

In the constructor you would want to be the least specific as possible.
Are you not using any special functionality of the HashSet class, you should favour referring to the Set interface, as this is much more flexible should you want to change implementation of the Data class later on - it also makes it possible for users of your class to use every class that implements Set rather than to be restricted of using the HashSet.

Do you however need special functionality of a specific class, you would of course then refer to that class.

Comment: Set<String> setOne = new HashSet<String>(); is coding to interfaces. It is Set on the left hand side so you can easily change the implementation from HashSet to another type of Set

Comment: Yes. I'm just using his example code, but in part 2 of my answer I'm saying exactly that (is it really that unclear?).
EDIT: Okay yes, i could still do it in my example...

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding right, are you asking if both `Set<String> Red = new HashSet<String>()` and `HashSet<String> Red = new HashSet<String>()` are allowed forms?